# UIAlertView not showing again

Tags: ios, uialertview

Im new too iOS .in my app i implemented an `UIAlertView` and want to not show the alertView again when user clicks on ok button and show alert view again if user clicks on cancel button. Please help me. tnx 
here is my code

```
    if (chek) {
            UIAlertView *alertView=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"  hi " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel " otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
                [alertView show];
    }

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
            NSString *buttontitle=[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
           if ([buttontitle isEqualToString:@"ok"]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sibche2://showapp/7030"]];
               chek=!chek ; }
            else if ([buttontitle isEqualToString:@"cancel "]){
                NSLog(@"hello my friend");
                chek=chek;
}
```

Comment: i think this code is correct.Please explain what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use UIAlertController because UIAlertView is deprecated. 
Then you should take a look at this delegate method from UIAlertView:

// Called when a button is clicked. The view will be automatically dismissed after this call returns

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

Here you can check which button was clicked without comparing a string but the index.

If you want to use the UIAlertView you can use:

```
//show alert whenever you need to
[[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Your error message here" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil]show];

//handle button click
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cancel action");
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
         NSLog(@"OK action");
    }
}
```

If you want to use the AlertController you can use:

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Your error message here" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel action")
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                   {
                                       NSLog(@"Cancel action");
                                   }];

    UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"OK action");
                               }];

    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
    [alertController addAction:okAction];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: hi lovo .tnx for ur heloping. actually i work with ios 7 and got confused with uialertcontroller.please help me more clear .tnx

Comment: as rcat24 and me already mentioned, the UIAlertView is deprecated and you really should use the UIAlertController

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an equivalent code for iOS 8, using the above lines might not work as expected on iOS 8.

[UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/)